# how to get value text using selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i want to get a text data from html using selenium but i don't know how, the data example is like this
Mama
from the html tag above I just want to retrieve the text mama using selenium python, can anyone help me?

I've tried it using get_attribute and get_property, but searching like that didn't work

Comment: Something like this: `element = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
  
# Get Text
print(element.text)`

Comment: provide the html code you try to get the text from and your code you try to do it with

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.